# Looking for AR (augmented reality) projects in Mathematica

Tags: image-processing, augmented-reality

I’m looking for any links or notebooks involving augmented reality. Any tools out there for Mathematica like ARKit?

Answer (score 9):

[image]

#### Examples of projects

- [Augmented Reality on Rotating Objects](https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/image-and-signal-processing/augmented-reality-on-rotating-objects.html)
- [How does a neural network that only knows beauty interpret the world?](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1369571)
- Augmented & Virtual Reality implementation in Wolfram Language (Wolfram Summer School 2018 project):

  - [Wolfram Community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1379131)
  - [Cloud notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/6ea211ad-1a73-4167-8e52-00e130288115)
- [Masking faces in a webcam stream](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/35026)
- Wolfram Community Group [Augmented and Virtual Realities](https://community.wolfram.com/content?curTag=augmented%20and%20virtual%20realities)

#### Parts of tech needed

One might think of AR as consisting of crudely two parts:

1. recognizing / identifying / processing reality
2. based on 1 blending new information into the processed reality

For these things you might need the basic tech stack:

- [Image Processing & Analysis](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ImageProcessing.html)
- [Audio Processing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/AudioProcessing.html)
- [Machine Learning](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MachineLearning.html)
- [Computer Vision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ComputerVision.html)
- [Neural Networks](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NeuralNetworks.html)
- [Wolfram Neural Net Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/)
- [Unity Game Engine Interface](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/UnityLink/guide/UnityLink.html)

Examples of Part 1 could be:

- [Image Identification Project](https://www.imageidentify.com/about/how-it-works)
- [Using Neural Networks to Locate a US Flag in an Image](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2034664)
- [Facial Emotion Recognition](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/908615)
- [Hand Gesture & Sign Language Recognition](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/908742)